# Needing to reload page for javascript to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a notification drop down (similar to facebook or most other social sites) which uses javascript to post the notifications. On most page loads this feature doesn't load until I refresh the page. Any idea why this might be?

I'm not hugely familiar with js to know off-hand so it may be a simple fix.

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&q=javascript+server+push+&meta=&gws_rd=ssl will give you some links to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Turbolinks enabled I guess. To resolve this problem you have to load your javascript field not only on document ready but also on page fetch.
In your `.js` files add loader for `page:load`

```
# will load .js content on document ready
$(function(){
    yourJavascriptFileNameInitialize();
});
# will load content when your route changes using Turbolinks
$(document).on("page:load",function(){
   yourJavascriptFileNameInitialize();
});

function yourJavascriptFileNameInitialize(){
    # put here your code
}
```

Turbolinks is by default enabled, it uses `ajax` to fetch new content for the page you load, to reduce content it loads from server (makes your app faster). When this happens you need to again load your `.js` files because they are loaded but no document ready has been recorded. Thus you have to load also when `page:load` events happens.

Comment: I do have turbolinks enabled. So you're saying in all my js files throw that code at the top and put my code in the yourJavascriptFileNameInitialize() function? Would I also do it for other .js.coffee files or just my application.js?

Comment: For all of your files, even `js.coffee` but in every file function `yourJavascriptFileNameInitialize()` has to be different, as the name said `yourJavascriptFileNameInitialize()`

Comment: Sorry for being "that guy" right now but it doesn't seem to be working. Just want to make sure I'm understanding you right. 

So application.js would look like:

`//=require jquery
...etc, yada yada
//=require turbolinks

$(function(){
    applicationInitialize();
});

$(document).on("page:load",function(){
   applicationInitialize();
});

function applicationInitialize(){
    # All my code for notifications here. 
}`

Comment: There is also one more thing (a very important one). You have to include your `applications.js` file in your `html` inside your `head` tag. `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Comment: Yeah, I've got that. I added your code to all the necessary files. Something must be missing. It's still only appearing on page reload.